# Series approximation for Pi up to n decimal places.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

I have the following series which gives me Pi.

[image: Pi series]

I need to figure out how many terms of the series I need to be accurate (with respect to Pi) up to 4 decimals.

I also need a formula to figure out how many terms of the series I will need to be accurate to n decimal places of accuracy. If I can find this formula, I should be able to answer the above question easily.

I believe I should be using the error bounds to determine this.

[image: Error bounds equation]

However, I don't understand exactly how this will tell me how many terms I need to be accurate to n decimals of Pi.

For example, how many terms would I need to be accurate to 100 decimal places using the equations above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternating series and hence the first term omitted gives a valid boud for the error.
Unfortunately, this implies that you should use $\approx\frac{10^k-1}2$ summands for $k$ decimals. Also note that your series converges to $\frac\pi4$, not $\pi$.

Comment: Noted, thank you. I ran through the equation above, and it was accurate to 3 decimals (3.141792614). Would it be appropriate to use $\approx\frac{10^{k+1}-1}2$ to make up for that decimal?

Comment: Ah, the error is of course correct for $\pi/ 4$ if you want the same accuracy after multipying with $4$, you should take four times as many summnds, .i.e. $\approx 2\cdot(10^k-1)$. Also note that an error of $\pm10^{-k}$ does not yet guarantee a correct $k$th digit. Anyway, to get even a decent accuracy (say, ten digits) is beyond reach with this simple series.

Answer (score 0):

To address the later remarks in your question, the error bounds come from considering the Maclaurin Series (Taylor series at $a=0$) for $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, and you are trying to evaluate $f(1) = \arctan(1)$. Here $f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^{2}},$ and the higher derivatives become rather unpleasant, though routine to calculate, quite quickly. But if you wanted to pursue it, you would set $a=0, x = 1$ and find the maxium possible value for the error term with $c \in (0,1).$
 There are slight variants of this formula which converge somewhat more quickly, for example $\frac{\pi}{4} = 4\arctan(\frac{1}{5}) - \arctan(\frac{1}{239})$ is a well-known formula.